# Login to WordPress using RCurl

Tags: wordpress, r, http, curl, rcurl

I would like to login into a WordPress website using R's RCurl package in order to install a WordPress plugin (probably use postForm on some options pages in WordPress).  Since the website is password protected, I ask for your help in how to authenticate my R session.

I found the following three links relevant, but do not know how to use them for WordPress:

- [login to mediawiki using RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370357/login-to-mediawiki-using-rcurl)
- [Login Wordpress using HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599982/login-wordpress-using-httpwebrequest)
- http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RCurl-HTTP-Post-td3311942.html

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've dealt with something similar using REDCap - might be useful for you too. This short example shows how I used the REDCap API to grab data.

```
library(RCurl)
out <- postForm("https://redcap.url.org/redcap/api/",
                 token="INSERT TOKEN HERE",
                 content="record",
                 type="flat",
                 format="csv",
                 .opts=curlOptions(ssl.verifypeer=FALSE))
write(out,file="C:/wherever/out.csv")
```

Note that this doesn't do proper checking for SSL - I've improved that in later versions. The more lengthy explanation is on my Google+ profile: https://plus.google.com/106259574970597769926/posts/U3fVCTV4EdQ

It looks like you can use cURL to log into Wordpress by passing the right parameters, as described here:
http://w4dev.com/wp/login-into-wp-using-curl/

It looks like the URL in question is `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php` and the parameters that matter can be found at the page above. Basically, you need to define the user, their password, and where you want to redirect them to on the site afterwards. These are how the parameters are described in that PHP example

```
"log=". $login_user .
"&pwd=" . $login_pass .
"&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=" . $visit_url;
```

Basically, it's just constructing a string to post, which looks something like:

```
http://yourwordpress.fake/wp-login.php?log=trehman&pwd=abc123456&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=http://yourwordpress.fake/pageyouwant
```

So, you could just change the postForm above to have a different URL and parameters, and it should get you authenticated and then redirect you to the page you want. I'm not an expert here, but I'm pretty sure that you can redirect to another long URL with parameters, which would let you "submit" a form or something similar.

Comment: Hello TARehman.  I've updated my question.  What I want is to be able to install a wordpress plugin by using R.
So I would need to be able to login, go to the plugin page, submit a form request for a plugin, find it - and "click" its installation.  Do you believe this is even possible?!

Comment: That seems like it's going to be pretty tough. From my understanding, the way that WP plugins are installed is that you click on a button which grabs the file, downloads it, and unzips it in the right place (basically the same as a manual installation, but done automatically). There's two big issues: one, you have to have your WP site set up to permit that (for instance, I run a site where we have to manually install plugins), and two, I don't know that the request is being made via HTTP POST. There's probably someone who knows more than I who can give a better answer.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use R to install the plugin?

Comment: Hi TARehman,
my real goal is to be able to create a blog post using knitr+rmarkdown and publish it into a WordPress website.  The problem is how to upload the photos into the server, and I am looking for various methods that might solve this.  One would be to use a WP plugin that knows how to upload such files, but I need to see how (or if) R can manipulate things in WordPress

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `XMLRPC` package to access wordpress

```
library(XMLRPC)
service <- "http://myblog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php"
xml.rpc(service, "wp.getUsersBlogs", "my@email", "secretpassword", .convert = TRUE)
```

The functions supported by this API are documented [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API). Using `wp.uploadFile` it might be possible to load photos into the server.

Comment: Hi Karsten.  Thank you for the suggestion, great idea.  (I knew about XMLRPC, but remember checking it some years ago and haven't touched it since - maybe it is time to go back to it :) )

Comment: Checking this again I see why I didn't think of it myself.  The wp.uploadFile was added only after WordPress 3.1.  I love seeing the evolution of WordPress.  Thanks again :)