# Reading HTML tables in R if login and other previous actions are required

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, html-table

I am using `XML` package to read HTML tables from web sites.

Actually I'm trying to read a table from a local address, something like `http://10.35.0.9:8080/...`.

To get this table I usually have to login into by typing login and password.

Therefore, when I run:

```
library(XML)
acsi.url <- 'http://10.35.0.9:8080/...'
acsi.df <- readHTMLTable(acsi.url, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
acsi.df
```

I see `acsi.df` isn't my table but the login page.

How can I tell `R` to input login and password and loggin on **before** reading the table?

Comment: if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980912/username-and-password-in-https-url) doesn't help, please provide an example url we can use :)

Comment: Hi, Anthony Damico. Unfortunately the login page I'm trying to enter via R runs through my LAN, then I cannot provide you it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general solution, you have to analyze the details of you login procedure, but package RCurl and the following link should help:

[Login to WordPress using RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879142/login-to-wordpress-using-rcurl)

Comment: Thank you, maybe I've found something there.